# How to get value of combobox from custom list view

Tags: android, android-listview, combobox

I have one application in that I have to show button and combo box in custom list view .I have add button and combo box using base adapter. But the value of combo box not found.I tried on selection listener but not work

![enter image description here][1]

Here I have combo box within list items and I want to retrive value from it for each list item

I tried the following code but not work

```
 holder.spindata.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

ComboBox b=view.findViewById(R.id.your_comboBox_name);

```
    //After that check that this combo Box checked or not

}
```

Comment: Yes it will work in Custom Adapter?If Not please mail your code on chavanjotiram24@gmail.com